# How to print a BYTE size number in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

Here is how to print numbers in word size. I can't make it work for byte size numbers.

```
.model  small
.stack   100h
.data
num  dw  300   ; <----- See below
numS db  6 dup(' '),'$'**

.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, num
    mov bx, 10         
    mov si, offset numS+5
    
    cmp ax,0
    jge next
    neg ax
 next:  
    mov dx,0
    div bx
    add dl, 48
    mov [si],   dl
    dec si
    cmp ax, 0
    jne next
    
    cmp num,0
    jge sof
    mov byte ptr[si],   '-'
    dec si
    
sof:
    inc si
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, si
    int 21h
    .exit
end
```

I changed `num dw` to `num db` but something is wrong in the code I tried to change bx ..
Can anyone change operand types to match because the program says it's the problem. I need this code to not use other methods like `pop`, `push`, `ret`.

Comment: Hint: use `int 21h` with `mov ah, 2` instead of `9`.

Comment: @Dai: How is that helpful?  A single byte can still represent up to 3-digit numbers (-128 to 127).  Storing into a buffer is an easy way to print in most-significant-first printing order.  If you switched to `ah=2`, you'd need to replace the system call at the end with a loop, and nothing else would change.  Given this starting code, the obvious thing is just to sign-extend the byte to a word.  (Or zero-extend after handling the sign.)

Comment: the problem that I need to print the numbers in an array that are one byte size like 2/26/25/78...

Comment: if it is more helpful here what i need to do : .model small , .stack 100 H ,.Data

Comment: A db 36,48,22,15,32,'$' , N equ 5 , code : mov ax @data , mov dx,ax ,mov si,0,mov cx,N, myloop: cmp A[si],A[si+1] , jg swich ,inc si ,dec cx, cmp cx,1, je final ,jmp myloop, swich: mov bl,A[si],mov al , [si+1] , xchg bl,A[si+1],xchg A[si], inc si ,dec cx,jmp myloop final: --- here I need to print the array but the numbers are in bit size and not word and the array must be bit sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The good news** is that you can keep using the conversion that you have. If you change the line `num dw 300` into something like `num db 36`, all you have to modify in the code is how you load the `AX` register. Instead of `mov ax, num`, you now write `mov al, num` `cbw`. (You're expecting signed numbers apparently!)

---

**An all bytes solution** is possible though:

```
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov al, num
    mov bl, 10         
    mov si, offset numS+5
    
    cmp al,0
    jge next
    neg al
 next:  
    mov ah, 0
    div bl        ; Calculates AX / BL --> AL is quotient, AH is remainder
    add ah, 48
    dec si
    mov [si], ah
    cmp al, 0
    jne next
    
    cmp num, al      ; AL == 0
    jge sof
    dec si
    mov byte ptr [si], '-'
sof:
    mov dx, si
    mov ah, 09h      ; DOS.PrintString
    int 21h
```